# Adding value to Swift dictionary with enum key

Tags: swift, dictionary, enums, key, addition

I defined Dictionary in Swift, with enum as the key and struct as value. At runtime I want to add value to the dictionary for a given enum key, however I get the following error:

'@lvalue $T9' is not identical to '(MyEnum, MyData)'

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A, B, C
}

struct MyData {

    var x : Int
    var y : Int

    init(x:Int, y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
} 

class Tester {

    let myDictionary = [MyEnum : MyData]()

    func dummy() {
        self.myDictionary[MyEnum.A] = MyData(x: 1, y: 2) // <-- error in this line
    }
}
```

Any idea how to do it properly ?

Comment: Might duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562357/how-can-i-use-a-swift-enum-as-a-dictionary-key-conforming-to-equatable

Comment: not a duplicate of that question, which is about an enum with an associated type so not automatically hashable

Comment: I checked this one, it doesn't demonstrate how to add new entries to the dictionary at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you’ve declared `myDictionary` with `let` rather than `var`.  Switch it to `var` and your code will work as expected.

Dictionaries are structs, which are a “value” type. That means when you declare them with `let`, they are frozen forever with the value they were assigned.  You can’t call methods that change their value, including assigning to them via a subscript (`[ ]`).

Unfortunately the error message isn’t super-helpful.  Ideally it would read something like “attempt to modify immutable value myDictionary”.

Don’t let this put you off using `let` though – it’s a great practice to use `let` by default unless you know you need to change a value.  But in this instance you do, so you need to use `var`.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. It works. btw, as I understand there's no way to have enum with properties (like in Java for example), otherwise I wouldn't have to define this additional dictionary and could combine the enum and its related struct data. Am I right ?

Comment: Enums can have both raw underlying types and associated values.  The link mentioned in the comment as a possible duplicate of your question was about how enums with associated values aren’t automatically hashable, take a look at that, or you can read the enums chapter in [the Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145)

Comment: I read the explanation about raw value, however it doesn't look the same as in Java where you can define enum with fixed values, like example 3 in the following page: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html

Comment: Not sure exactly which one you mean by example 3 but this is an equivalent of what I think you mean: `enum Currency: Int {
    case Penny = 1
    case Nickle = 5
    case Dime = 10
    case Quarter = 25
};

let coin = Currency(rawValue: 25)`

Comment: yes, this is what I meant, but what you wrote is not exactly as in the java example... according to this example I would like to write let coin = Currency.Quarter. And Quarter can holds also some other attributes...