# Swift: How to encode a hash map with enum as the key?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, encode, multipeer-connectivity

I have enum like this:

```
   enum Direction : String {
      case EAST  = "east"
      case SOUTH = "south"
      case WEST  = "west"
      case NORTH = "north"
    }
```

And I have a variable called result which is a Hashmap using these enum direction as the key.

```
var result = [Direction:[String]]()
```

I tried to encode this object and send to the other side through the multipeer framework. However, it fails at the encoder.

```
aCoder.encode(self.result, forKey: "result")
```

Error says that:
"encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17045f230'

How can I encode this Hashmap?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that it's Swift convention to use `lowerCamelCase` for enum cases (this isn't Java!). I also assume you're referring to `Dictionary` when you say Hashmap. Also `var result = [Direction[String]]` is not valid Swift, did you mean `var result = [Direction : [String]]()` or `var result : [Direction : [String]]`?

Comment: Here's a duplicate article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562357/how-can-i-use-a-swift-enum-as-a-dictionary-key-conforming-to-equatable

Comment: yes, i mean var result = [Direction : [String]]()

Comment: It is not a duplication of the question.

What i am asking is how to serialise (encode) the object.

Comment: Related: [How do I encode enum using NSCoder in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326645/how-do-i-encode-enum-using-nscoder-in-swift).  Use the enum's `rawValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in JAL's comment `NSCoding` feature is based on Objective-C runtime, so you need to convert your Dictionary to something which is safely convertible to `NSDictionary`.

For example:

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    var nsResult: [String: [String]] = [:]
    for (key, value) in result {
        nsResult[key.rawValue] = value
    }
    aCoder.encode(nsResult, forKey: "result")
    //...
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let nsResult = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "result") as! [String: [String]]
    self.result = [:]
    for (nsKey, value) in nsResult {
        self.result[Direction(rawValue: nsKey)!] = value
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: What if my set is in this structure:

[AnotherEnumType: [Direction: [String]]]

Why I failed to write 
var nsResult: [String: [String:[Tile]]] = [:[:[Tile]]]

Comment: @user6539552, please edit your question and show more concrete example with specifying how `AnotherEnumType` and `Tile` are defined.